# Configuring destination name in Spring @JmsListener

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-jms, spring-java-config

I have Spring-based component that needs to be able to communicate via JMS and would like to use a `@JmsListener` annotated method to do so. My listener class needs to read a JSON-encoded payload, but also needs to read some custom header.
I have set up a `@Configuration` bean and added it to the current XML based configuration, in which I configure the necessary message converter. Currently my listener method is annotated like this:

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "activemq:queue:queue.name")
    public void handleItemCommand(ProvisionItemCommand itemCommand, @Header(AUTH_HEADER_NAME) String auth) {
```

This all works but obviously the queue name can't be hardcoded, it needs to be configurable. To complicate matters, we use some custom class to read configuration data, so using `@PropertySource` and properties file is out of the question.

Where I keep getting stuck is seeing how to set things up so this can happen. The Spring 4.2 reference documentation tells me to create and register a custom `PropertySource` class (which could be backed by our custom config code) but the example in the doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-property-source-abstraction) is just creating an application context on the fly and adding the custom property source to that.
Maybe I have developed a blind spot here, but how do I create a custom property source and add it to the environment that's already there? I've found several partial examples around the web, but most are for Spring 3, and some seem to be contradicting.
I'd be grateful if somebody can clear this up as I think I'm 99% there but somehow the final 1% fails to "click" for me.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, as doing the simplest thing I could think of actually seems to solve my problem.
In my `@Configuration` class I added the following:

```
@Autowired
public void setCustomConfiguration(CustomConfiguration customConfiguration, ConfigurableEnvironment env) {
    LOG.trace("setCustomConfiguration()");
    this.customConfiguration = customConfiguration;
    env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new CustomPropertySource("custom-config", customConfiguration));
}
```

Then the `CustomPropertySource` class simply looks up whatever key it is asked for in it's `CustomConfiguration`. Posted here in hopes it helps somebody else; if anyone has any remarks/improvements on this solution I would be glad to hear it.